# Waiting for redirect in Capybara Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec, capybara

I am doing some integration tests on my website that is builtin Spree. I am using RSpec + Capybara in order to do these tests.

I found that in the newer versions of Capybara, wait_until was removed from the source code because it is not necessary anymore to wait for an AJAX Request this way. Somehow, now Capybara is smart enough to wait for the AJAX Requests.

What I am doing is quite simple:

```
visit product_path(product)
  within '.vip-buy-content' do
    first('.buy-button').click
  end
expect(page.current_path).to eq(cart_path)
```

When the button is clicked, an AJAX request is done. When the AJAX request is done, a redirect happens.

However, the expectation fails because it seems that Capybara will process this faster than the AJAX request and the redirect.

If add a "sleep 10" above the expect, the spec will pass because it has enough time to process this.

I would like a nicer way to wait for the redirect. Any ideas?.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve this problem, but I usually add a wait_for_ajax.rb file in my supports folder, and create a module such as this.

```
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
end
```

And then add

```
visit product_path(product)
  within '.vip-buy-content' do
    first('.buy-button').click
  end
  wait_for_ajax
expect(page.current_path).to eq(cart_path)
```

My assumption you are using :js=>true on your describe blocks. Hope this helps!

Comment: I used this alternative before, I found it in another post. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: It might depend on the javascript engine your using for capybara. I tend to use phantomjs through the gem poltergeist because it's a headless javascript engine.

Comment: I am using Poltergeist with PhantomJS too.
I think I haven't been clear before: The problem is that I make an AJAX Request and when it's done the user will be redirected.
With this, maybe Capybara will wait for the ajax request to be done. However, it might check "too fast" before the redirect is done?

Comment: I honestly think that using this or the sleep is the only way to wait for ajax requests. I had the same problem, but with a much slower computer, so I had to make 30 second timeouts.